# .NET Core: apparent and real assembly of a type are not the same

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm writing a template engine in .NET 8 on basis of Roslyn and I stumbled on this phenomenon:

- The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-8.0) says `List<>` is in assembly System.Collections
- `typeof(List<>).Assembly` says `List<>` is in assembly System.Private.CoreLib
- When I build some compilation which uses `List<>` and I add System.Private.CoreLib but not System.Collections to the references, I get an error:

  > error CS0012: The type 'List<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Collections, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I hope someone can shed some light on this and explain why and how this works on a deeper level.

I'd also like to know how to get a reference to the "real" assembly if I only have the type (in this case `typeof(List<>)`)

Thanks,
Kc

EDIT:
From the answer(s) I already got, I can now reformulate my last question:
Given a Type (e.g. `typeof(List<>)`), how can I get the reference assembly that defined it?

Comment: System.Collections is a special type of assembly called [reference assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/reference-assemblies) while System.Private.CoreLib contains its implementation. What exactly you are trying to do here? What is your goal? It's weird to analyze types on template generation to be honest...

Comment: I try to create a compilation at runtime that contains all references to assemblies that are needed in some user-supplied code. The user defines the Type that he wants to use in that compilation and I add the assembly for that Type. I hope this was comprehensible.

Comment: To be clear: I do not try to create a template. I try to parse a template including some C# code in it. I then try to compile it to get an executable.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Basic.Reference.Assemblies/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I got the hints from freakish and Hans Passant, I found out about [Type forwarding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/type-forwarding) and also found that the forwarded types can be found from each assemly with `Assembly.GetForwardedTypes()`.

So the solution to my question how to get the reference assembly for a certain type is:

```
var referenceAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(a => a.GetForwardedTypes().Contains(forwardedType));
```

That's under the assumption that the reference assembly is already loaded in the current AppDomain.

Thanks everyone for helping out.

P.S.: The related project can be found at https://github.com/DeLoooping/De.Loooping.Templates
Feedback is welcome.